# Can one choose a specific repository for the Ubuntu setup process to use when installing from the live CD?

Tags: repository, setup, installation

I know a very fast repository I often use to install packages,  I would dearly like to use this when I am setting up Ubuntu, the mirror used by setup when the region is choosen is usually very slow, this results in apt configuration taking a long time.

I usually have to remove network connectivity from the machine I am setting up and the setup process will quickly complete. I then use synaptic to change to the fast repository before installing all those large packages I need, it would be much smoother though, if I did not have to do this and could feed the setup process repository information before hand.

I am wondering if I use the synaptic package manager in the live session and select a repository if the selected repository will be the one used during setup or will the setup process use the one it thinks is best usually a local mirror?

Comment: Did you ever try if it works?  ;-)

Comment: I have not tried, the thought came to me while I was writing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot into the live session (not installer), open synaptic, change repository, refresh and without restarting open Install Ubuntu from Desktop.

Ubuntu live cd has a virtual RAM drive where changes are recognised.

Comment: Good, that is what I was thinking, did you try it?